# Ng-Bootstrap (Angular Bootstrap) Not working properly

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm having issues getting Angular bootstrap working and am wondering if anyone has had similar and can offer help?

I have:

followed the instructions on the website
[Like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mp5jO.png)

- I've made sure I added the @import to my styles file as we are using
  SCSS, I've even tried also adding the CSS to the styles section in my
  angular.JSON
- Created a Module import file which I am importing into the main
  module, this will contain all individual imports (right now it's just
  NGBDropdown)
- Checked The versions

This is the code and then the result:

```
      <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
        <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
          <button ngbDropdownItem>Action - 1</button>
          <button ngbDropdownItem>Another Action</button>
          <button ngbDropdownItem>Something else is here</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

[Don't mind the colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7750d.png)

It is also not functional at all -
It is obviously broken, as the dropdown items are outside and dropdown button does nothing.

Comment: Hey @DavidG, welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you please be a bit more specific on what you mean by "It is also not functional at all"? What are you expecting should happen and what is/is not happening.

Comment: Done, sorry, I thought the picture attached showed how broken it was.

Answer (score 1):

I made a working example of your code with **Angular** and **Ng-bootstrap**. Look up what does **differ** from **your project** from the working **Stackblitz**. The code you posted do work if you import **Ng-boostrap** correctly. [Dropdown menu Ng-bootstrap Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pwtddy?file=src/app/dropdown-manual.html)

Comment: I have looked at this stackblitz and am I missing something. I thought I just import the components I want. Do I need to create a component for each bootstrap piece I want - including the code etc from the website? I thought that the point was just to install and use in your other components.

Comment: I don't think you need to create a separate component for each component like I did in the example. I just made it according to the documentation of Ng-bootstrap. https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-bootstrap/ Look at the second example I think that's what you want to achive.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working. I had skipped ng add and did it manually sa per the steps but something was missed I guess. I used ng add this time and it was fine...